# Generative Models VS. Configuration Models

Tags: graph-theory, complex-networks

How should I explain the difference between Generative Models and Configuration Models in Complex Networks in simple terms.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A generative model is a statistical model of the type `P(G|t)` that outputs a degree distribution based on its form and parameters [[source]](http://www2.imm.dtu.dk/~tuhe/cnmml/pdf/clauset.pdf) whereas a configuration model is a sequence of nodes with a fixed degree, that you can then randomly connect to create a network [[source]](http://networksciencebook.com/chapter/4).

So you can use a generative model to create configuration models but you can't necessarily infer the generative model from the configuration model.